# Kentor MVC Logout don't call logout url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

I've an issue on this feature.
SignIn action works well with ADFS and return to AuthServices/Acs
But Logout action don't call ADFS and redirect directly to returnUrl parameters (checked it with fiddler).
I'm calling this link : `/AuthServices/Logout?ReturnUrl=~/&Status=LoggedOut`

web.config is set up as this :

```
  <kentor.authServices entityId="https://localhost:2181/AuthServices" returnUrl="https://localhost:2181/">
    <identityProviders>
      <add 
        entityId="https://ADFS DOMAIN/adfs/services/trust" 
        signOnUrl="https://ADFS DOMAIN/adfs/ls" 
        logoutUrl="https://ADFS DOMAIN/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0" 
        binding="HttpPost"
        allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" 
        metadataLocation="https://ADFS DOMAIN/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
        wantAuthnRequestsSigned="true">
        <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/*****.cer" />
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
  </kentor.authServices>
```

If I launch `https://ADFS DOMAIN/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0` on another tabs, it is working, I return on signin page from my website.

So it seems to be an internal issue to retrieve logouturl and send it ?

Thanks  for helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of requirements that need to be met before logout request will be issued:

1. You need to have a `http://kentor.se/AuthServices/LogoutNameIdentifier` claim and its issuer has to match the IDP that you're trying to logout from.
2. You need to have `http://kentor.se/AuthServices/SessionIndex` claim.
3. Your AuthServices IDP configuration needs a `logoutUrl` (I see you've specified this but probably it's easier to let AuthServices read it from the metadata)
4. You have specified a `ServiceCertificate` with either Signing or Both usage (i.e. not just Encryption)
5. Your AuthServices IDP configuration has `DisableOutboundLogoutRequests` =
   false (this is the default)

Missing claims (first two points) is the most likely issue if you have some claims transformation happening during login or you are not retaining the original ClaimsIdentity. See also the documentation regarding ClaimsAuthenticationManager, e.g. https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/doc/ClaimsAuthenticationManager.md

You can turn on logging and see which of these points are failing:
https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/v0.21.2/Kentor.AuthServices/WebSSO/LogOutCommand.cs#L155-L170

Comment: Thank you for your response. ADFS don't send claimtype as http://kentor.se/AuthServices/LogoutNameIdentifier or http://kentor.se/AuthServices/SessionIndex. How can I set up web.config (or maybe adfs) to have this ? But adfs is not on my side.

Comment: ADFS doesn't send them, but the default AuthServices ACS code adds them to the identity during login. I added a link to ClaimsAuthenticationManager in the answer above

Comment: See also some discussion here: https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/665

Comment: I'm using the default MVC connection. The SignIn process runs well and the return is AuthServices/Acs, but nothing is added in ((ClaimsIdentity)(User.Identity)).Claims. Is there any default ClaimsAuthenticationManager  or I should create an custom ?